# Can not import opencv in python3 in Raspberry Pi3?

Tags: python-3.x

Any solution for this error ?, need help :(

I import cv2 in python3:

```
import cv2
```

and it results like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libQtTest.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 12):

Use this:

```
sudo apt install libqt4-test
```

Reference:

- [RPi-Stackexchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83648/how-can-i-use-opencv-with-python-3-on-a-raspberry-pi)

Answer (score 8):

You can install opencv-python  in raspberry with the following commands:

```sh
pip3 install opencv-python 

sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev 

sudo apt-get install libjasper-dev 

sudo apt-get install libqtgui4 

sudo apt-get install python3-pyqt5 

sudo apt install libqt4-test
```

Comment: Worked like a treat, thanks! I had to use `pip3 install opencv-python==3.4.6.27` though because the latest version of opencv is apparently incompatible with Raspberry Pi at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

**Here are the steps to solve your problem**

1. First uninstall opencv-python

> sudo pip3 uninstall opencv-python

`
 2. install opencv using the CMake

3. Install CMAKE developer packages

> sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config -y

4. Install Image I/O packages

> sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev
>   -y

5. Install Video I/O packages

> sudo apt-get install libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev
>   libv4l-dev -y
>
> sudo apt-get install libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev -y

6. Install the GTK development library for basic GUI windows

> sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev libgtk-3-dev -y

7. Install optimization packages (improved matrix operations for OpenCV)

> sudo apt-get install libatlas-base-dev gfortran -y

8. Install Python 3 and numpy

> sudo apt-get install python3 python3-setuptools python3-dev -y
>
> sudo pip3 install numpy

9. follow this link for more details [HOW TO INSTALL OPENCV 3.4.0 WITH PYTHON 3 ON RASPBERRY PI 3](http://life2coding.com/install-opencv-3-4-0-python-3-raspberry-pi-3)

Answer (score 1):

on on rasphberry pi, you have to build opencv from source.

The easiest is to get a USB flash of 8 GB or more, you must format it to `NTFS` or `EXT4`. The build needs about 6GB of space.

install required packages using

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake pkg-config libjpeg-dev libtiff5-dev libjasper-dev libpng12-dev libgtk2.0-dev libgstreamer0.10-0-dbg libgstreamer0.10-0 libgstreamer0.10-dev libv4l-0 libv4l-dev libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libv4l-dev libxvidcore-dev libx264-dev libatlas-base-dev gfortran python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib libgtkglext1-dev v4l-utils python2.7-dev python3.5-dev python3-pip python3-numpy
```

follow the commands below but care fully.

```
cd ~
wget -O opencv.zip https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/archive/3.2.0.zip
unzip opencv.zip
```

if you have enough space on the PI SD card (16GB or more)

```
cd ~/opencv-3.2.0/
```

if you use the flash then

```
cd /media/pi/
```

press the tab key to autocomplete the command.

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-3.2.0/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
    -D ENABLE_NEON=ON /home/pi/opencv-3.2.0

sudo make -j4 install
```

A successful build will take you approximately 3.5 to 4.5 hours, the pi may slow down in speed during this point but it is worth it.

Now You Can Install using

```
sudo make install
```

REMEMBER THAT if you installed opencv using pip or pip3 you must uninstall using

```
pip uninstall opencv-python
```

or

```
pip3 uninstall opencv-python
```

Only then will opencv work for both python2 and python3 on your rasphberry pi.

Answer (score -1):

pip install opencv-python==3.3.0.10

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```html
sudo apt-get install libQtTest-dev
```

thanks.